# Array formula works in the sheet but invalid in conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, conditional-formatting

I have a list of time intervals along with their convenience ratings. I wish to highlight intervals rated anything other than impossible which conflict with those rated impossible.
I use start1 and end1 named ranges to refer to the interval endpoints and convenience is self-explanatory.

I couldn't do it with ISBETWEEN, but the following formula appears to correctly return true for all such intervals and false for others:

```
=OR(ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF($C1<>"impossible", 
     IF(GTE($A1,FILTER(start1,convenience="impossible")),
        IF(LTE($A1,FILTER(finish1,convenience="impossible")),TRUE)
     )
  )))
```

However, when I enter this in Conditional Formatting it is rejected as invalid formula.

How can I add it to the conditional formatting rule?

Here's [the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18U_e5bb6dwN8Ddd7LgaeVNw9RpD825SQqVtOZTRldl4/edit?usp=sharing). The data in question is the sheet named "TEST" (the last one).
The formula has been entered in column P.

Comment: Hi and welcome. You say _I wish to highlight intervals rated anything other than impossible which conflict with those rated impossible_ Would you please edit your spreadsheet (and include a snapshot in your question) to provide an example of how the conditional formatting would appear if you had a successful outcome. Perhaps it is just me, but I'm confused about the specific columns/rows to which you want to apply conditional formatting.

Answer (score -1):

It was very simple. I had just forgotten that in conditional formatting, references to named ranges must be made using the INDIRECT function.